# Revenuecat React-Native iPad Purchases.purchasePackage - promise not settling

Tags: ios, react-native, testflight, revenuecat

using

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"react-native-purchases": "^3.0.6",
```

We're having a problem on an 11" iPad running through testflight on iOS version 13.3.1. Everything works on all simulators, and our iPhones and other iPads running on testflight work properly as well.

The problem is that the promise returned by Purchases.purchasePackage is neither resolving nor rejecting - it hangs. After combing thru the native Obj-C code, I've found relevant code in the file Pods/Purchases/RCPurchases.m. The method

```
- (void)purchaseProduct:(SKProduct *)product withPayment:(SKMutablePayment *)payment withPresentedOfferingIdentifier:(nullable NSString *)presentedOfferingIdentifier completion:(RCPurchaseCompletedBlock)completion
```

is getting invoked, and the line

```
[self.storeKitWrapper addPayment:[payment copy]];
```

is called, but the callback method

```
- (void)storeKitWrapper:(RCStoreKitWrapper *)storeKitWrapper
     updatedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
```

is never invoked. Could this be an underlying issue with SKPaymentQueue?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the purchase starting though? Do you see the prompt to pay and the "Purchase is successful" on the iPad?

Comment: When I was still experiencing this problem, no, I didn't see the purchase starting or any of those prompts. I unfortunately didn't check the exact iOS version where this was happening, but it was a flavor of iOS 13.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out my iPad was actually using an older version of iOS. Updating it resolved the issue.